# BaseAdapter.GetView method is not called even if the list count is greater than 0

Tags: c#, android, baseadapter, android-gridview

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

This method is not called even if the count is greater than zero.

I want to know the exact behavior of GridView and BaseAdapter.

I tried as much as possible but the GetView method is not triggered.

Code Snippet:

```
    internal class SymbolAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {

        private object[] m_items;
        internal SymbolAdapter(Context context, Object[] items) : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            m_items = items;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return m_items.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = null;
            object item = m_items[position];
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.LayoutParameters = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(85, 85);
                imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
                imageView.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                view = imageView;
            }
            else
                view = convertView;
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran Edited my question

Comment: share the code which is in convertView==null condition block

Comment: @Reena updated the code snippet inside the block

Comment: Sorry, I dont know abt C# but where you initialize context globally..? and are you getting any crash.?

Comment: Not crash. I want that GetView(..) method to be triggered during run time. So that i would get an output.

Comment: Actually, your view is empty. at-least, you can give background for the ImageView and check. or print some log in that to check whether it's loading or not, If it's not loading, Add the code which calls this adapter class

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran It won't be effective, because the ImageView instance is initialized only when the GetView method is called. Hope you understand ?

Comment: 1GetView()` will not be called until the adapter is instantiated and the adapter is made known to the `GridView`. In Java, the connection is made with `GridView#setAdapter(ListAdapter)`. Are you making this connection? If so, can you show the code?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling your adapter from somewhere? And also please make sure your list is not being initialized after adding some items in it. Because your code given above looks good to me.

Comment: @Cheticamp yes i initialized the Adapter property in GridView class. After that i received 2 hit on Count property of the SymbolAdapter class after that it completes its execution without calling GetView method.

Comment: @ZohaibHassan Okay i will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved when i tried to add the view prior to creating the instance for BaseAdapter to the Adapter property of the GridView.

Thanks,